# В MySql кирилица записывается иероглифами

Tags: mysql, node.js

Node JS v8.9.1
TypeScript 2.6.1

Вывод команды `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%char%'`:

```
character_set_client       utf8  
character_set_connection   utf8  
character_set_database     utf8  
character_set_filesystem   binary  
character_set_results      utf8  
character_set_server       utf8  
character_set_system       utf8
```

Пробую при помощи библиотеки [mysql](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql) записать данные в базу на хостинге, но кириллица пишется иероглифами, на локальном сервере MySQL все пишется корректно. Все файлы в проекте, подключение к базе и входные данные в UTF-8.  Проверил уже всё что мог, но не могу найти причину по которой в базу пишутся иероглифы.  Может кто то сможет дать подсказку что еще можно проверить.

Код на котором проводилось тестирование:

```
import * as mysql from "mysql"

let connection = mysql.createConnection({
    user: "login",
    password: "***",
    database: "bazaname",
    host: "hosting.ru",
    port:3306
})

connection.connect()

connection.query('INSERT INTO `info`(`ordertime`, `ordertimefmt`, `ordertype`, `orderamount`, `orderform`, `ordercode`, `cadnum`, `useripaddr`, `useragent`, `userphone`, `exectime`, `exectimefmt`, `orderstatus`, `uuid`) VALUES ("1513230713158","2017-12-14T00:51:53.158Z","1",-100,"{\\"region\\":\\"Москва\\",\\"city\\":\\"\\",\\"street\\":\\"\\",\\"type_street\\":\\"\\",\\"house\\":\\"\\",\\"apartment\\":\\"\\",\\"t1\\":\\"1\\"}","","66:41:705006:719","192.168.1.123","","81234567890","1513230713158","2017-12-14T00:51:53.158Z",1,"c630f86b-9333-4f02-b980-230dcf945017");')
connection.end()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел рабочий способ, но не знаю насколько он правильный.
Сразу после подключения к БД выполнить запрос `SET NAMES utf8` и кириллица будет писаться в нормальном виде.

Comment: так при создании таблици укажи что кодировка по умолчанию  UTF8

**вот тебе пример**

CREATE TABLE `TEXTS`(
    `id` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY UNIQUE ,
    `big_text` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL ,
    `small_text` VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL ,
    `datetime` DATETIME NOT NULL
)ENGINE = MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET =utf8 COLLATE = utf8_unicode_ci;

Comment: @dpi Кодировка при создании таблицы устанавливалась как UTF8. По какой причине появлялись иероглифы без дополнительного запроса, я не могу понять.

Comment: а у тебя от сервера приходит украинский текст??

Comment: @dpi При создании таблицы у меня не было прописано `COLLATE = utf8_unicode_ci`. У меня в базе не используется украинский текст.

Comment: так мой совет тебе подмог?

Comment: @dpi Увы нет. Даже после пересоздания таблицы с указанием `COLLATE` все равно пишутся иероглифы. Думаю я остановлюсь на том варианте который указан в моем ответе.

Comment: в пыхе есть вот такая функция почитай может на ноде тоже что то такое есть  htmlspecialchars($row['ter_name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')